# ItemsControl in other ItemsControl (DataTemplate in other DataTemplate)

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol

i have problem while i want to use one itemscontrol in other itemscontrol.

for example :
i want draw contest start grid ... so you need  rows, and in every rows, you need columns :)

Horizontal data = round1, round2, round3, round4
and vertical data are : startpoint1, startpoint2, startpoint3

results are :

```
Round1
-------------------------------------------------
|startpoint1|startpoint2|startpoint3|startpoint4|
    user1       user2       user3        user4
-------------------------------------------------

Round2
-------------------------------------------------
|startpoint1|startpoint2|startpoint3|startpoint4|
    user1       user2       user3        user4
-------------------------------------------------

Round3
-------------------------------------------------
|startpoint1|startpoint2|startpoint3|startpoint4|
    user1       user2       user3        user4
-------------------------------------------------
```

but i cannot make work one itemcontrol in other :(

```
<UserControl
x:Class="WpfApp6.View.Draw"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp6.View"
xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:model="clr-namespace:WpfApp6.Model"
Width="1150"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance model:MODEL_ViewModel}"
d:DesignHeight="450"
Background="Red"
mc:Ignorable="d">



<Grid Margin="0,0,10,60" Background="AliceBlue">


    <ItemsControl
        Width="770"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Background="DarkBlue"
        ItemsSource="{Binding HORIZONTAL_DATA}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>



                <ItemsControl
                    Width="200"
                    Height="200"
                    Margin="50"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Background="Cyan"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding VERTICAL_DATA}">

                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                            <label text="VERCITAL_ITEM" />

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                </ItemsControl>


            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

    </ItemsControl>


</Grid>
```

Comment: What does the object that you're binding to look like? What doesn't work specifically (does it show the horizontal data but not the vertical)?

Comment: Data loks like on picture here : https://ctrlv.cz/XnSq
Problem is that, only horizontal data are OK, vertical data isnt show.  BUT if u but vertical code section outside horizontal, it works both. if i insert vetrical section into horizontal, vertical isnt work :(

Comment: https://ctrlv.cz/igFO

Comment: Those pictures aren't really helping... do you have a minimal code snippet from your application, like the class you're binding to, so that we would be able to reproduce the issue with your own code?